# Scala - Explanation for regex statement

Tags: regex, scala, capturing-group

Assuming I have a dataframe called df and regex as follows:

```
var df2 = df
regex = new Regex("_(.)")
for (col <- df.columns) {
      df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed(col, regex.replaceAllIn(col, { M => M.group(1).toUpperCase }))
    }
```

I know that this code is renaming columns of df2 such that if I had a column name called "user_id", it would become userId.

I understand what withcolumnRenamed and replaceAllIn functions do. What I do not understand is this part: `{ M => M.group(1).toUpperCase }`

What is M? What is group(1)?

I can guess what is happening because I know that the expected output is userId but I do not think I fully understand how this is happening.

Could someone help me understand this? Would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the [`replaceAllIn`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@replaceAllIn(target:CharSequence,replacer:scala.util.matching.Regex.Match=>String):String) method is

```
replaceAllIn(target: CharSequence, replacer: (Match) ⇒ String): String
```

So that `M` is a [`Match`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex$$Match) and it has a [`group`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex$$Match@group(i:Int):String) method, which returns

> The matched string in group i, or null if nothing was matched

A *group* in regex is what's matched by the (sub)regex in parenthesis (`.`, i.e. one symbol in your case). You can have several *capturing groups* and you can name them or refer to them by index. You can read more about capturing groups [here](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) and in the Scala API docs for [`Regex`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex).

So `{ M => M.group(1).toUpperCase }` means that you replace every match with the symbol in it that goes after `_` changed to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

`M` just stands for match, and group (1) refer to group (1) that is captured by regex. Consider this example:

> World Cup

if you want to match the example above with regex, you will write something like this `\w+\s\w+`, however, you can make use of the groups, and write it this way:

```
(\w+)\s(\w+)
```

The parenthesis in Regex are used to indicated groups. In the example above, the first `(\w+)` is group 1 which will match `World`. The second `(\w+)` will match group 2 in regex which is `Cup`. If you want to match the whole thing, you can use group 0 which will match the whole thing.

See the groups in action here on the right side:
https://regex101.com/r/v0Ybsv/1